# Accessesing saved JSON response in column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, sqlite, httparty

Okay, I am using HTTParty to save a JSON response in my show.subsources column. Subsources is a text type column.

For example, one of my subsources: column currently has the data saved as so:

```
[{"source"=>"hulu_free", "display_name"=>"Hulu", "id"=>6001348,"link"=>"http://www.hulu.com/watch/843378"}]
```

To me, this looks like a hash within an array. How do I access each hash within the array, so that I can correctly display the "source" name in my views?

What I have tried is:

```
<% showdata = show.subsources %>
<%= showdata[0]['sources'] %>
```

I am expecting that to display 'hulu_free', but instead it will not show anything in my views. Am I not using the right syntax to access that hash? Or am I not saving the JSON correctly in order for me to access the hash data? Do I need to parse the data first? I have spent way too long trying to figure this out.

Comment: Have you tried `<%= showdata[0]['source'] %>` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can easily get JSON representation and parse it to Hash.

```
text = text = %q{[{"source"=>"hulu_free", "display_name"=>"Hulu", "id"=>6001348,"link"=>"http://www.hulu.com/watch/843378"}]}
text.gsub!('=>',':')
JSON.parse(text) # => returns hash
```

I'm not sure how internals work in your program, but probably you should consider to put JSON like text into this field.